# Implicitly Unwrapped Optional Types - Possible Typo?

Tags: ios, swift

From the [Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID453) documentation:

> ### Implicitly Unwrapped Optional Type
>
> The Swift language defines the postfix ! as syntactic sugar for the named type ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional, which is defined in the Swift standard library. In other words, the following two declarations are equivalent:
>
> ```
> var implicitlyUnwrappedString: String!
> var implicitlyUnwrappedString: String!
> ```
>
> In both cases, the variable implicitlyUnwrappedString is declared to have the type of an implicitly unwrapped optional string. Note that no whitespace may appear between the type and the !.

Am I missing something?  Both lines look exactly the same to me, why wouldn't the two declarations be equivalent?

Comment: am I the only one who's looking to the declarations again and again trying to find a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that makes no sense. You'll find the correct version in the Swift book:

> In other words, the following two declarations are equivalent:
>
> ```
> var​ ​implicitlyUnwrappedString​: ​String​!
> ​var​ ​implicitlyUnwrappedString​: ​ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional​<​String​>
> ```

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/de/jEUH0.l

Comment: Didn't even think to check that (oops) - still, I would think they would update the eBook and the site at the same time.